# couldn't pass value from textbox to select input

Tags: jquery

In my code, I have following lines to get the value from textbox input and set one of options as selected in select input according to this value.

```
var category_name = jQuery('.categoryNameTextbox').val();    

//alert(category_name);

jQuery('.categoryDropdown').val(category_name);
```

I can get "category_name" successfully, but I couldn't set the option in select input. However, if I use the following line to test, i can set "rent" as selected option in select input perfectly.

```
jQuery('.categoryDropdown').val("rent");
```

Anyone knows what is going on here? Thank you in advance.

Here is my code. My purpose is set selected option in dropdown list according to the value in the textbox

```
<select class="categoryDropdown"><option value="">Select</option><option value="buy">Buy</option><option value="sell">Sell</option><option value="rent">Rent</option></select><div style="display: none;"><input type="text" class="categoryNameTextbox" value="rent"></div>
```

Comment: What does your HTML look like?

Comment: Is the return of `category_name` actually an option in your select input?

Comment: If `VALUE` and `TEXT` are different in `<option value="VALUE">TEXT</option>`, then `.val("TEXT")` won't work.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming want want to get the selected option text value from your text input. If your questions is referring to option `value=""`and not text then just replace `text` with `val` in the below code.

```
var $textbox = $('input').val();
$('select option:selected').text($textbox);
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/TLw3G/

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found my problem. Because there is a space in the value getting from textbox, there is no match among values in options